# How to upgrade Laravel 6 project to Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, upgrade

I've been asked on my job to update a Laravel 6 project to version 9. I'm having a lot of issues, i can't even test the project cause it's giving me a lot of errors.
First i wanted to check the exact laravel version (i've been told it's 6.2), but I can't even check it with php artisan --version or use php artisan...
Also I would like to know how to do the update, since i can only find enough information to update from 8 to 9 on the official website.

Thanks.

Things i've tried:

-Changed this on composer.json:

"require": {
"php": "^7.3|^8.0",
.....
},

-Tried this composer commands:

composer update
composer install
composer update --no-scripts
composer require laravel/framework

-I get this errors:

During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with Arr
ayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users*******\
Documents\Project\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:1277

or

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Thanks.

Comment: Do yourself a favor: https://laravelshift.com/ (it's been well worth the subscription cost in my experience, and you can subscribe for just a month to do the upgrade)

Comment: " it's giving me a lot of errors" - with the current version, or with the updated one?

Comment: Read and follow the [upgrade guides](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade) for every version

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have experience in Laravel? Or any experience upgrading versions in Laravel projects? If no, then maybe it would be better to explain it to your supervisor.

Comment: laravelshift.com or a brand new project. All other options are just wasting of your time.

Comment: Right now i'm not sure I am able to use laravelshift, that's something my boss must allow, but ill ask. For the moment I need to try to do it for myself. I'm getting the errors after just trying to execute the laravel 6 project. Also, i have few experience with Laravel, i've been learning it for 2 months before working on this proyect.

Comment: This sounds a bit like you try to run your Laravel 6 application with a pretty recent PHP version. Which one do you currently use?

Comment: Yeah, i'm using php 8.1.12 . Im trying to make composer update and it's giving me this kind of error: require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.12) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Well, then the problem is obvious: your application is not compatible with PHP 8. Please run it with PHP 7 instead

Comment: As mentioned use shift or follow the upgrades guides that each version has [https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to upgrade laravel 6 to 7 with success.

- The first problem was that my PHP version was too high, apparently higher versions does not work for the upgrade, so I had to downgrade PHP (im using Xampp so i just had to change 'apache' and 'php' folders on Xampp folder from 7.2.5 version).
- My project had some external dependencies that I had to upgrade first before running 'composer update'. This was the main problem and I didn't know about that. (In my case barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper and laravel/ui).

After I fixed that things, I just ran 'composer update' and everything was working. I'll try to upgrade now to laravel 8 and 9, hope it's the same. Thanks to everyone for the answers and hope this can help others.